# Excel addin. when opening up an excel sheet with addin formulas already in it, the formulas get corrupted intermittently

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula, office-addins, excel-addins

Javascript excel addin. when opening up an excel sheet with addin formulas already in it, the formulas get corrupted intermittently. How do we prevent formulas from being corrupted?
Similar to below github issue perhaps.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2051

Proper formula name:

ABC.GET_PB_OPT_ORDER_ANALYSIS()

Corrupted name:

=BloombergUI.xla!_xldudf_ABC_GET_PB_OPT_ORDER_ANALYSIS()

Formulas auto correct to the proper name when the addin is reloaded. This can be either through readding the addin through the 'Insert' Tab and 'My Addins'. Or by clearing the excel cache and letting the addin reload itself on Excel restart.

BloombergUI is a COM addin that is added. But disabling the addin just causes the corrupted formula to update to "='C:\blp\API\Office Tools\BloombergUI.xla'!_xldudf_ABC_GET_PB_OPT_ORDER_ANALYSIS()" upon excel restart